# Get partial body while guzzle is still downloading it

Tags: php, guzzle

I have a relatively simple guzzle request:

```php
$client = new Client([
  'base_uri' => $request_base
]);
$response = $client->request('POST', $request_path, [
  'form_params' => ['key' => 'value']
]);
echo $response->getBody();
```

Right now I'm getting the body when it finishes downloading but I need to get the partial body every few seconds while it is being downloaded.

I looked at the documentation for a while, I'm guessing I have to make an async request but I'm not sure how I would access the partial body.

I can only use php and sockets, besides that I'm open to use another library/piece of code if it will mean a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass the `stream` option to the request method.

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $request_path, [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::STREAM => true
]);
$stream = $response->getBody();
```

Now `$stream` contains an instance of `Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface` which you can read by chunks of a selected length.

```
while (!$stream->eof()) {
    $chunk = $stream->read(1024);
    # ...
}
```

It's only possible to read it by chunks of fixed size. If you need to read the response line by line, for example, you'll need to rearrange the chunks yourself. You can modify the code bellow easily to split over different delimiters as well.

```
/** @return Generator<string> */
function readStreamLines (StreamInterface $stream, int $chunkSize = 1024) : Generator {
    $last = '';
    while (!$stream->eof()) {
        $chunk    = $stream->read($chunkSize);
        $lines    = explode("\n", $chunk);
        $lines[0] = $last . $lines[0];
        $last     = array_pop($lines);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            yield $line;
        }
    }

    yield trim($last);
}

foreach (readStreamLines($stream) as $line) {
    # ...
}
```